# How to define a custom gate from a matrix in TKET

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, pytket

I'm currently learning all about different quantum tools such as qiskit, tket, cirq, Forest SDK and so on. I just want to create a circuit that gets executed given a matrix, because a circuit can be written as a matrix and the other way around. In qiskit, cirq and pyquil (Forest SDK) there is no problem in defining an own gate. I don't find any function in tket which could help with this.

For example I want to define an AND gate. For those who don't know, an AND gate is actually just the CCNOT or CCX Gate. Tket does support the CCX gate but if I want to create maybe an AND Gate with 3 or 4 Qubits (CCCX or CCCCX) Gate the tket framework doesn't help.

Can somebody help me with this? I understand that you can define own gates in Tket but that just include gates that are created from native gates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define custom parametrised gates in pytket using `CustomGateDef`. Here the `CustomGate` is defined using a circuit which implements the desired unitary instead of the  matrix itself. Here is an example for how to do this taken from the [user manual](https://tket.quantinuum.com/user-manual/manual_circuit.html#custom-parameterised-gates).

```python
from pytket.circuit import Circuit, CustomGateDef
from sympy import symbols

a, b = symbols("a b")
def_circ = Circuit(2)
def_circ.CZ(0, 1)
def_circ.Rx(a, 1)
def_circ.CZ(0, 1)
def_circ.Rx(-a, 1)
def_circ.Rz(b, 0)

gate_def = CustomGateDef.define("MyCRx", def_circ, [a])
```

Its also possible to define a custom subroutine from a circuit using [CircBox](https://tket.quantinuum.com/user-manual/manual_circuit.html#circuit-boxes). The Custom parameterised gates shown above are useful when you want to define a parametrised gate in terms of lower level gates which you can then use repeatedly with different parameter values.

If the unitary represents a one, two or three qubit operation it is possible to synthesise a circuit to implement the unitary. See the manual section on [unitary synthesis](https://tket.quantinuum.com/user-manual/manual_circuit.html#boxes-for-unitary-synthesis).

If you're interested in multi-controlled X operations you can add these to your Circuit as a CnX. You can have as many controls as you like. Here the we pass in the qubit indices as a list with the last element being the target qubit.

```python
from pytket import Circuit, OpType

circ = Circuit(4)
circ.add_gate(OpType.CnX, [0, 1, 2, 3]) # CCCX gate
```

You may also wish to check out the [ToffoliBox](https://tket.quantinuum.com/user-manual/manual_circuit.html#multiplexors-state-preperation-boxes-and-toffolibox) feature which implements an arbitrary permutation of the computational basis states using either {X, CnX} gates or a sequence of multiplexor operations.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The snippet I showed is for a CCCX gate but you can make as may controls as you like by using a longer list of qubit indices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The Problem with CustomeGate is that it needs a circuit which implements the desired matirx. I want to start from a matrix and work my way to the circuit. I had a look at the Unitary Boxes but for my application i want more then just 3 Qubits to work with.

Is there any way to go from the matrix (maybe given as a numpy.array) to a circuit. This feature is available in qiskit, cirq and pyquil.

Comment: Arbitrary unitary synthesis in not implemented in TKET for > 3 qubits. A decision was made not to include this as the algorithms scale badly with respect to two-qubit gate count and runtime.

As a workaround you could define your gate in qiskit and convert it to TKET using the `qiskit_to_tk` function from the pytket-qiskit extension. You may need to supply a method to decompose your new gate first.

There are special box types that can be decomposed efficiently for a larger number of qubits. See `ToffoliBox` and `PauliExpBox`. Depending on what you are doing these could be useful.

Comment: "A decision was made not to include this as the algorithms scale badly with respect to two-qubit gate count and runtime." I think this is an interesting point, is there any public documentation of this decision? I could not find it along the issues of the tket Github page.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I have a great answer to this. I don't think it's discussed explicitly in the documentation. 

I'm a contributor to TKET so I'll make a note to mention this in our docs. I also recently had another request from someone else asking for the same thing. I think is worth discussing having this as a feature to be used in numerical calculations etc.

Comment: Thanks for your insights into the project.